# How to modify the algorithm to reduce the delay?

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, dynamic

I have a lot of inputs like this where user enters value:

```
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="Milk" ONKEYUP="convcase(document.convert.Milk.value)">
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="Buckwheat" ONKEYUP="convcase(document.convert.Buckwheat.value)">
```

and a lot of calculation like this:

```
document.convert.Fe.value = BuckwheatFe * document.convert.Buckwheat.value + PeaFe * document.convert.Pea.value + MilkFe * document.convert.Milk.value + ...
document.convert.Hexadecanoic.value = BuckwheatHexadecanoic * document.convert.Buckwheat.value + PeaHexadecanoic * document.convert.Pea.value + MilkHexadecanoic * document.convert.Milk.value + ...
```

so the result after calculation shows dynamically and when the program has hundreds of products the delay between input and count is too large. I calculate all products: milk, buckwheat... even if the user does not enter their value.

Could you advise me how to modify the algorithm to reduce the delay?

Comment: you can cache the results if they do not change between invocations of your code.

Comment: Don't calculate on keyup, use blur or change. Instead of `document.convert.Milk.value` you can use `this.value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach it something like the following. The inputs that need to be used in the calculation can be denoted with a class, say "itemValue", and retrieved once then cached. This supposes that they don't change.

The markup can look like:

```
<form name="convert">
  Milk: <input class="itemValue" name="Milk" onkeyup="convcase(this)"><br>
  Buckwheat: <input class="itemValue" name="Buckwheat" onkeyup="convcase(this)"><br>
  Fe value: <input name="Fe"><br>
  Hex value: <input name="Hexadecanoic"><br>
</form>
```

Things like the Fe and Hexadecanoic values can also be cached. It also helps if the collection of nodes is converted to an array so that built–in array functions can be used. These may be slower than using a for loop, so if they are, convert the *reduce* call to a loop.

```
// Helper to convert a NodeList to an array so built-in methods can be used
function toArray(list) {
  var i = list.length, arr = [];
  while (i--) {
    arr[i] = list[i];
  }
  return arr;
}
```

The function that does the actual work:

```
var convcase = (function() {

  // Cache stuff in a closure. Note that the names of each factor set
  // must match the form control name where the related total is written
  var factors = {
       Fe: {Buckwheat:0.5, Milk:0.75},
       Hexadecanoic: {Buckwheat:0.6, Milk:0.82}
      };
  var nodes;

  return function (el) {

    // Only get nodes the first time, assumes they don't change, and convert to Array
    // This can be done before validation as it's not dependent on it
    nodes = nodes || toArray(el.form.querySelectorAll('input.itemValue'));

    // Validate el.value here and deal with invalid values.
    // Only proceed if it's a valid value

    // For each set of factors, do all the calculations and write totals to form
    for (var factor in factors) {

      // Get the factor set
      var set = factors[factor];

      // Write the total to the related form control
      el.form[factor].value = nodes.reduce(function(sum, node){
                                         sum += node.value * set[node.name];
                                         return sum;
                                       }, 0);
    }
  };
}());
```

I wouldn't do this on keyup, I'd wait for the change or blur events so calculation was only done when there was a good chance the user has finished for the moment, otherwise there may be lots of useless calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Store elements in the array and use looping . Also you can store previous values (old one in some other array ) and before performing calculation compare the old value with the new one . If the value changed then only do it .

Answer (score 0):

I know a standard way to handle this.  The point is: you don't want every key stroke to trigger the algorithm.  You want to wait for the client to stop typing (for a while); then you trigger the algorithm.

(EDIT: by the way, read the comments below.  You might be helped just by changing "onkeyup" by "onchange")

With a clearTimeout/setTimeout combination you can do exactly that.  I set the 'typing time' to 400ms, feel free to change this value.

```
<script>
var timer = null;
var interval = 400;  // feel free to change this value

function imputChanged(elm) {
  // if any previous key stroke happend less than 400ms ago; clearTimeout will cancel that request.
  // only the last request will trigger executeAlgorithm().
  clearTimeout(timer);  
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
      executeAlgorithm(elm);
    },
    interval
  );
}
function executeAlgorithm(elm) {
  // do what ever you have to do here. As an example, I show the value in a div
  document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML = elm.value;
}
</script>
<input onkeyup="imputChanged(this)">
<div id="messages"></div>
```

(EDIT: it looks like onkeyup works better on IE than onimput; I now set the trigger to onkeyup)

Comment: Why use a timer when the *change* event does what you are trying to do using available functionality?

Comment: What I posted, I use for things like autocomplete; where you want to see results while you are typing; just not necessarily after every key stroke. If it is only needed to trigger the algorithm after the client stopped typing (and blurs the imput), then yes, you are absolutely right.